# (MPAndroidChart-LineChart) I didn't get the last label in my app

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I use MPAndroidChart v3.0.2 now. 
The problem is that lasst data('05일') is not showing...

This is the value while I get on Debug
xVals : 1일, 2일, 5일

and It is the source and the result screenshot.

I think the '5일' enter the 'red circle'... but I don't know the reason..

```
  LineChart chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    if (ExRegList.length() == 0) {
        chart.clear();
        chart.setDescription(null);
        chart.setNoDataText("데이터가 존재하지 않습니다."); // There is no data.
        chart.invalidate();
    } else {
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        final String[] xVals = new String[ExRegList.length()];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < ExRegList.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = ExRegList.getJSONObject(i);
                String date = obj.getString("REG_DT").split("-")[2] + "일";
                xVals[i] = date;
                int score = obj.getInt("ANSWER02");
                switch (score) {
                    case 1:
                        entries.add(new Entry(i,3f));//매우만족
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        entries.add(new Entry(i,2f));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        entries.add(new Entry(i,1f));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        entries.add(new Entry(i,0f));//매우불만족
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "");
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2);
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(true);
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
        lineDataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
        lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false);
        lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
        chart.setData(lineData);

        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
        XAxis bottomAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        bottomAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        bottomAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
        bottomAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        bottomAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        bottomAxis.setLabelCount(entries.size());

        YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.setLabelCount(4, true);
        yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0.0f);
        yAxis.setAxisMaximum(3.0f);

        yAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase yAxis) {
                String format = "";
                switch ((int) value) {
                    case 3:
                        format = "매우 만족";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        format = "만족";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        format = "불만족";
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        format = "매우 불만족";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return format;
            }
        });
        yAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        YAxis yRAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
        yRAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
        yRAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        yRAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        chart.setFocusable(false);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        chart.setDescription(null);
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        chart.animateY(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInCubic);
        chart.invalidate();
```

[image]

Comment: Hah, helped again :) See my answer. I've tested it and it is working now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
bottomAxis.setLabelCount(entries.size());
```

Use this overloaded version:

```
bottomAxis.setLabelCount(entries.size(), true);
```

Second parameter, `boolean force` forces to have exact number of labels. Without it, sometimes the method doesn't work, like in your case. From source code you can see:

> sets the number of label entries for the y-axis max = 25, min = 2,
>   default: 6, be aware that this number is not fixed (if force == false)
>   and can only be approximated.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot!! Why I miss this point...I've seen about it.. Thanks!!
You always save my time. Thanks!!

Comment: Sir, could you see one thing..?? I read almost write about it, but I didn't resolve it...!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142361/videoview-is-not-showing-but-i-can-hear-the-sound

Comment: Still it is not shwoing

Comment: I had the same question but in my case i want the LAST label to be visible in case. Not necessarily show all the label but atleast last lable should be visible

Answer (score 1):

bottomAxis.setLabelCount(entries.size(), true); and also set margin right to make visible last count.

Comment: how to set margin ?